# Need clarification for the Copy sharing mode of Files Connect

Tags: files, file-storage, files-connect

We want to connect Google Drive as a Connected Source. We want also share files with external users. That's why Reference sharing mode is not an option in our case. While reading the documentation:

[Enable Salesforce Files Connect for Your Organization](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_files_connect_enable.htm&type=5)

[Files Connect Setup Guide](https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/30000000TwBg/oY6nj5H8L_c0djY2t01Q5s39DqCk82b5lLKTOl9Aeuc)

I didn't understand the Copy file sharing option to its full extent. So my questions are the following:

1. Does the Copy sharing mode consume File Storage?
2. If it consumes the storage, is it possible to select which files would be copied to Salesforce and which wouldn't? Because there are many files (100 GB in total) in Google Drive, we don't want to keep them all in Salesforce. However, from the documentation I got an impression that it's all or nothing.

Comment: I too have the same doubt since the documentation is not entirely clear on that, did you find the anwser?